# Force open video in android webview with specific app in device

Tags: android, video, webview, android-webview, android-permissions

I am building a Web App for android. I haven't started learning Android Development so I decided to build it in ASP.NET. I want to force open a video for example with MX Player. If mx player is not installed on device the video will not open and show a pop up that requires mx player installed for video to be played. And also what permission does it require?
It is a simple webview I watched on youtube.

Comment: "I want to force open a video for example with MX Player" -- why would the user want this behavior?

Comment: @CommonsWare , sir I would really appreciate if you would help me because I don't have the slightest idea about android development. But answering your question is that I don't want to show my video url link.

Comment: @aldoblack : The closest you can get to this (easily) is to use a "chooser" which shows the user a list of apps which can play the video and allows the user to pick one. Just for reference though, MX Player will show the URL at the top of the screen when first starting and whenever it is paused.

Comment: @Squonk , it is vlc player that shows the url not mx player. Anyway, how can I use a "chooser" ? Can you help me with the code? As I said above I do not know how to code in android. only asp.net.